# Why won't my wifi driver load from the non-free debian install image when selected?

Tags: debian

I've downloaded the non-official image of debian which includes non-free drivers, [you can find it here](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/9.8.0+nonfree/amd64/iso-cd/).

When at the "detect network hardware" step of the installation, it shows me a list of drivers that are loaded, I need the rtlwifi package since I'm using an rtl8822be (specifically I need the rtlwifi/rtl8822befw.bin driver).

The rtlwifi package is listed but when I select it the screen goes blank for a couple seconds and then returns to the same network hardware detection interface. This happens for any network driver I choose.

What's going on here? I'm aware I can install the driver online, but this is not an option since I do not have an ethernet port or a usb to ethernet adapter.

**EDIT:** I've included a snippet from /var/log/syslog. It looks like it can't find the appropriate firmware.

```
Apr 14 10:59:27 ethdetect: insmod /lib/modules/4.9.0-8-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko 
Apr 14 10:59:31 main-menu[238]: edia failed: Invalid argument
Apr 14 10:59:31 main-menu[238]: (process:5761): mount: mounting /dev/mmcblk0p5 on /media failed: Invalid argument
Apr 14 10:59:31 main-menu[238]: (process:5761): umount: can't umount /media: Invalid argument
Apr 14 10:59:31 main-menu[238]: (process:5761): mount: mounting /dev/mmcblk0p5 on /media failed: Invalid argument
Apr 14 10:59:31 main-menu[238]: (process:5761): mount: mounting /dev/mmcblk1p1 on /media failed: Invalid argument
Apr 14 10:59:31 main-menu[238]: (process:5761): umount: can't umount /media: Invalid argument
Apr 14 10:59:31 main-menu[238]: (process:5761): mount: mounting /dev/mmcblk1p1 on /media failed: Invalid argument
Apr 14 10:59:31 main-menu[238]: (process:5761): mount: mounting /dev/sda1 on /media failed: Device or resource busy
Apr 14 10:59:31 main-menu[238]: (process:5761): umount: can't umount /media: Invalid argument
Apr 14 10:59:31 main-menu[238]: (process:5761): mount: mounting /dev/sda1 on /media failed: Device or resource busy
Apr 14 10:59:31 main-menu[238]: (process:5761): mount: mounting /dev/fd0 on /media failed: No such file or directory
Apr 14 10:59:31 main-menu[238]: (process:5761): umount: can't umount /media: Invalid argument
Apr 14 10:59:31 main-menu[238]: (process:5761): mount: mounting /dev/fd0 on /media failed: No such file or directory
Apr 14 10:59:31 main-menu[238]: (process:5761): modprobe: FATAL: Module usb not found.
Apr 14 10:59:31 main-menu[238]: (process:5761): modprobe: FATAL: Module usb not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.0-8-amd64
Apr 14 10:59:31 main-menu[238]: INFO: Menu item 'ethdetect' succeeded but requested to be left unconfigured.
Apr 14 10:59:32 main-menu[238]: INFO: Falling back to the package description for brltty-udeb
Apr 14 10:59:32 lilo-installer: LILO not usable on EFI PCs without BIOS compatibility; use grub-efi
Apr 14 10:59:35 main-menu[238]: INFO: Falling back to the package description for brltty-udeb
Apr 14 10:59:35 main-menu[238]: INFO: Menu item 'di-utils-shell' selected
Apr 14 11:01:25 net/hw-detect.hotplug: Detected hotpluggable network interface lo
Apr 14 11:01:26 check-missing-firmware: looking at dmesg again, restarting from \[  344.933886\]
Apr 14 11:01:26 check-missing-firmware: timestamp found, truncating dmesg accordingly
Apr 14 11:01:26 check-missing-firmware: saving timestamp for a later use: 
Apr 14 11:01:26 check-missing-firmware: /dev/.udev/firmware-missing does not exist, skipping
Apr 14 11:01:26 check-missing-firmware: /run/udev/firmware-missing does not exist, skipping
Apr 14 11:01:26 check-missing-firmware: no missing firmware in loaded kernel modules
Apr 14 11:01:54 main-menu[238]: INFO: Falling back to the package description for brltty-udeb
Apr 14 11:01:54 lilo-installer: LILO not usable on EFI PCs without BIOS compatibility; use grub-efi
```

Aditionally, I've tried loading the firmware I found [here](https://packages.debian.org/stretch-backports/all/firmware-realtek/download) from a USB, both by including the .deb and by decompressing and including the lib/ directory inside a /firmware/ directory with no luck.

Comment: See what appears in syslog when you choose the driver and get back to the same screen. The installer provides a way to view the log or even to export it to some external storage.

Comment: @FerencWágner, I've updated the question with a snippet of the log.

Comment: It does not detect any missing firmware. Spawn a shell in the installer environment, and `cat /proc/modules` to see if the wifi driver module (rtlwifi?) is loaded at all (use `grep` if necessary). Also check `dmesg` manually for messages emitted by the driver (either loaded or not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the driver I needed was not included by default in the non-free image. I ended up downloading and installing the rtlwifi_new repository from github post-installation.